# Reads an integer and print all perfect number smaller than given integer

Tags: c++, perfect-numbers

I can find perfect numbers but I can't print all perfect numbers smaller than a given integer.

```cpp
int main() {

    cout << "Enter a number ";
    int number{};
    cin >> number;
    int sum{};

    int j{};
    for (int i = 1; i < number ; i++) {
        j = number % i;
        if (j == 0)
            sum = sum + i;
    }
    if (sum == number){
        cout << sum;
```

I expect the output `6 28 496` for `input=500`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I could't find any way

Comment: What are *perfect numbers* ?

Comment: @preciousbetine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number

Comment: Can anybody help me

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for the link.

Comment: What you currently get as output for 500?

Comment: @preciousbetine nothing

Comment: I'll give you a hint. Right now, your code is checking if the number entered is a perfect number. What would you have to change to determine which numbers between 1 and the entered number are perfect numbers?

Comment: @FredLarson I can't find the solution

Comment: Bigger hint: you'll need to use a nested loop.

Comment: Sorry, I wish i could solve

Comment: Create a function with your code and use the function to check if a number is a perfect number. Iterate in a loop from 1 to input and check each number with this function. Print the number of it's a perfect number.

Comment: Do i need create a function? Because i haven't learned yet

Comment: No, it's not necessary. It helps making it simpler but if you haven't learned functions yet it won't be simpler. Create the nested loops. What is your current problem?

Comment: I couldn't create the nested loops

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've mushed your "is it perfect" logic with your "all numbers under the given limit" logic together to where you aren't getting desired results.

I'd take your test and put it in a function.

```
bool isPerfect(int number) {
    int j{}, sum{};
    for (int i=1; i<number; i++) {
        j = number % i;
        if (j == 0) sum = sum + i;
    }
    return (sum == number);
}
```

Then call that function repeatedly with all integers smaller than the given input:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number ";
    int number{};
    std::cin >> number;
    for (int n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
        if (isPerfect(n))
            std::cout << n << " ";
    }
}
```

[image: Output given limit of 30 = 6 28]

Course you could still do it all in your main() function, but it's a lot clearer when you break it up.